# windbg command line to capture child process and make a breakpoint

Tags: windbg

recently I have to debug an app with windbg, after reading [WinDbg Command-Line Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I found some solutions for either problem, but none could solve all these problems in a single run.

Ganerally, I use **-c** option to make breakpoint on startup, use **-logo** option to output logging content to a static file, use **-pn** option to launch my app, so initially I have my command like this:

```
windbg -pn myapp.exe -logo "log.txt" -c 'bp WININET!InternetSetCookieExW "r; dv; kb; .dump /mu cookiedbg.dmp; g"'
```

This command would start **myapp.exe**, create a breakpoint at **WININET!InternetSetCookieExW** WIN32 API, when this breakpoint is hit, it dumps info to **log.txt** and then continue (by **g** command).

However, I still have some problems unsolved, below lists my actual requirements:

1. Since my app would create child process, windbg should be able to debug the main process and all child processes
2. **Everything should be automated**, so windbg should make a breakpoint at my app's startup, logging some infomation on breakpoint

For the **1st** point, I found the **-o** option debugs all childprocess, so `windbg -pn myapp.exe -o` seems work>

But unfortunately, when an **-o** option is give, everytime a child process is forked, windbg hits a breakpoint, I have to manually use **g** command to continue, and this is not automated.

For this, I then found **-g** option, which will ignore the initial breakpoint, but it still raise a critical probelm.

The problem is, when **-g** option is specified, the commands provided by **-c** option could not be executed immediately after my app launches, since the initial breakpoint is ignored, I have to raise a breakpoint manually, then my commands could be executed on that hit.

I tried **-e** option to raise some event for break, but got no result.

To sum up, I use **-o** and **-g** options to make windbg catch all childprocesses and do not hit the initial breakpoint when a process is created, but then I couldn't inject commands via **-c** option.

Thanks if someone could help to give the correct combination of commandline options.

Comment: If you know in advance the set of child processes then you can use the Image File Execution Options facility to automatically debug them. This can be used instead of having one instance of windbg debug all the child processes.

Answer (score 0):

you could omit the **-g** option and add **g** to the initial command like this:

```
-c 'bp WININET!InternetSetCookieExW "r; dv; kb; .dump /mu cookiedbg.dmp; g"; g'
```

so after the initial breakpoint and command execution, you resume the execution of the debuggee process.

at least it solved my problem